# Gmail blocked emails sent from Send Grid

Tags: sendgrid

We are trying to send mail on to Gmail account by using send grid api but Gmail has blocked the email which is sent from send grid. Please check the message given below:

550 5.7.1 [167.89.24.147 12] Our system has detected that this message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for more information. kw15si11591084pab.218 - gsmtp

We have checked all header parameter suggested by Send Grid and implemented it in our code. At the same moment, it works fine for other domain like AOL, Rediff etc.

Please suggest how we overcome with this problem as we have huge users on Gmail and we will send our emails to all those users as. Also, we have noticed that the email came after some time from Send Grid.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For what its worth - I set up sendgrid thru Azure and am using and sending to gmail addresses w/o any issue whatsoever. Just posting this here for anyone from the future if they encounter similar problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recipient mail server analyzed your message and determined that the content of the message is spammy. My recommendation would be to run your formatted message through a third-party service, www.mail-tester.com , to identify ways to improve the reception of the message. It's also possible that your sending IP address, 167.89.24.147 based on the response message you've included, is listed on a black list. You'll want to scan your sending IP on a site like http://multirbl.valli.org/ and, if you see that your IP is listed anywhere, submit a delisting request with the black list.

SendGrid also has a Spam Checker app - Turning on SendGrid's Spam Checker app can help combat this, as you're able to set a predefined filter and get alerted when your content exceeds the filter that you set.